# ESD diode current specification

Tags: voltage, current, esd, tvs, static

I'm using this [ESD diode](https://semtech.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#E0000000JelG/a/2R0000001TBb/1Sb_xwpUbvH6q70WnqQwnuIuQfNX7THrFXZCKGHIIn8) for an Ethernet application.

The clamping voltages and the working voltage values are satisfied.

But I am not sure about the current values.
The minimum peak current is given as 1A. I want to know whether the 1A is really required for ethernet applications? Isn't it too high ?

Can someone tell me what value of current (peak current) of the ESD should be right for ethernet/usb applications?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *The minimum peak current is given as 1A. I want to know whether the 1A
> is really required for ethernet applications? Isn't it too high ?*

The peak current of 1 amp is when a surge occurs. For normal standard ethernet operation, nowhere near 1 amp will be flowing.

<sub>By the way, I believe you mean 1 amp p-p (as mentioned in the data sheet).</sub>

> *Can someone tell me what value of current (peak current) of the ESD
> should be right for ethernet/usb applications?*

Here is the specification regarding ESD: -

[image]

- You need to look into what the equivalent circuit of the ESD generator is in IEC/EN 61000-4-2
- Model it in a simulator (fairly easy actually)
- Model the TVS
- Run a simulation to find the peak positive and peak negative currents

It'll be the same peak current for any low voltage application so, no need to make distinctions between ethernet and USB. EN61000-4-2 ESD generator (from a simple web search): -

[image]

Image from [here](https://en-support.renesas.com/knowledgeBase/9270297).

So, if the 100 pF capacitor is charged to 30 kV, the maximum current surge will be about 91 amps. But, this will reduce due to cable inductance and capacitance (which you need to model).

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Andyaka. So, the peak current of 1A is during a surge. So, does it mean that we design and select the device only for a surge current of 1A? My confusion is how the peak current of 1A is fixed with respect to the ethernet application?

Comment: No, the peak current may be a lot higher than this; you need to calculate or simulate it. The 1 amp figure is barely of any consequence whatsoever. Maybe you should explain which page of the data sheet you refer to when you say 1 amp so I can double check this.

Comment: I'm referring to the Electrical characteristics table. Over there in the clamping voltage specification, I see the clamping voltage as 5.5V max at 1A of peak pulse current. That's the 1A current that I am referring to. Could you please check and clarify my confusion

Comment: In the same table (right below) it also says 10.5 volts and 10 amps and, 18 volts at 25 amps. The current is what the ESD generator might force through the TVS. You need to simulate this to get an accurate figure for current for your situation. As I said in my answer, it might be as high as 91 amps @Newbie <-- there are no short-cut easy answers to this; you either guess and get it wrong or you calculate/simulate AND you need to take into account the cable characteristics.

Comment: Oh Ok. So, the maximum current depends on the ESD generator, right? Thank you for the clarification. I have accepted the answer

Comment: You can simulate the generator voltage waveform with linear rising and falling waveforms.